# Correct usage of multiple indices in SQL (SQL Server 2014)

Tags: sql, sql-server

New to creating indices in SQL Server. Suppose I have 3 columns `A, B, C` none of which are my primary key. I am creating many queries with `WHERE` clauses that contain any and all combinations of these. So, some `WHERE` clauses may include only A, others A and B, others B and C, some all three, etc.

1. Should I create an index for each of these combinations?
2. Should they include these columns as "Included Columns" (as in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a **compound** index on `(A, B, C)`, but only if your queries always use the **n left-most columns** of that index, that is:

- you always query using all three columns in your `WHERE` clause
- or you use `A` and `B`
- or you use just `A`

A compound index on `(A, B, C)` will **NOT** work for queries:

- using `B` and `C`
- only `B`
- only `C`

If you have queries like that, then yes, you might need to create three separate indices on each of the columns separately.

But remember: while an index *might* speed up your queries, it will **always** cause maintenance overhead on `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` (since the index must be kept in sync with the actual data in the table).

So **fewer indices** are better - don't **over-index**! That's often worse than having no indices at all...

Comment: Thanks - so should they be of those "included columns" type of index?  Also, in your example, would a query on `A` and `C` work?

Comment: @dashnick: a query must use the **n left-most columns** in the index definition - the left-most (`A`), the 2 left-most (`A`, `B`), or the 3 left-most (`A`, `B`, `C`). None of that covers A+C - so **no**, for A+C this index is **useless**.

Comment: Included columns are great if you need to provide a few more columns from your query - but included columns **cannot** be used in the querying, e.g. they cannot be used in the `WHERE` clause

Comment: and also, the maintenance is obviously only done if i edit one of A,B, or C, correct?

Comment: @marc_s, Whether Index ordering i.e., left most columns only applicable to where condition or also applicable to join on conditions?

Comment: @RGS: to joins as well - the compound index is **never ever** usable if you're not referring to to the **n left-most columns** of it.

Answer (score 2):

2) Included Columns are just for storing and returning of the data, they have no impact on speed of the filter. However, you can use them to avoid accessing the table itself (one less index search). If you for example select column F where A, B are filtered by, you can create index((A,B) include (F)) and it will be as fast as if (A,B) was PRIMARY KEY on the table. F data however will be doubled in the DB.

1) It all depends on what exactly are you doing, how many rows there are in the table and so on. In general, if you always select multiple rows, indices will not help you - they will be ignored if you select 1000 rows for example. Reason being that SQL Server, after searching within the index, needs to search each of the rows in another (PRIMARY KEY) index separately and just searching whole table from top to bottom is faster.

In case SELECT returns one or few rows, marc_s's answer is applicable.

Comment: thanks! I actually would be returning many rows, so I guess indices won't help after all!

Comment: @dashnick
In that case only index with included all columns that you are selecting  may be applicable, or change in CLUSTERED index:

eg. if you have table OrderProducts where there is OrderId and OrderProductId and you most often select all order products for one order - You can use (OrderId, OrderProductId) as PRIMARY KEY. But note that you will need to put OrderId into WHERE clause even when only selecting one order product by OrderProductId (eg WHERE OrderId = oid AND OrderProductId = opid instead of WHERE OrderProductId = opid) for clustered index to not be ignored.